# Handle Onclick(on tap) event for iPhone Map Annotations

Tags: iphone

I have plotted annotations in iPhone Map, now I need to handle the onclick/ontab event for the annotation. Please provide the ways to do that.

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 2):

When annotation gets selected map view calls `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` method in its delegate, so to handle tap event you should implement that method in your map delegate.

Answer (score 0):

First you should give title to pins.If you give then only the delegate method`mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`. tou can handle now.